# Send form via jquery: Access to strict mode caller function is censored

Tags: strict-mode

I just want to save a simple SP Form via another Button (I need to set some Workflow parameters first).

```
submitForm = function() {   
    if (oldStateSTR != csCustomForms.fieldsARY.LabelProcessStateInternal.inputOBJ.val() )
    {
        csCustomForms.fieldsARY.WorkflowState.inputOBJ.val("Pending");
    }
    $('[id$=SaveItem]').trigger("click");   
}
```

This worked perfectly for another project (same farm). But now I only got the JS error *Access to strict mode caller function is censored*

Can I simply disable the strict mode (what ever that is)?
thanks a lot...
-dave

Comment: I come from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234423/sharepoint-2013-access-to-strict-mode-caller-function-is-censored). Can you tell us if you found a workaround? Thank you