# SharePoint 2013: Access to strict mode caller function is censored

Tags: 2013, button

I have created a clone button of "Save" button. When I modify any field and save it with the click of this clone button, it is saved. But while attaching/removing any file and saving this change using the click of this clone button, I got below error:

```
Access to strict mode caller function is censored
```

Any help in this !!

---

Below is the workaround provided in [link](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2016/02/12/wtf-microsoftajax-js-vs-use-strict-vs-firefox-vs-ie/).

```
function hackEventWithinDoPostBack() {
    var originalEventDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Window.prototype, "event");
    var hackEventVariable = false;
    var eventPropertyHolder;
    Object.defineProperty(window, "event", {
        configurable: true,
        get: function get() {
            var result = originalEventDescriptor ? originalEventDescriptor.get.apply(this, arguments) : eventPropertyHolder;
            if (result || !hackEventVariable)
                return result;
            return {};
        },
        set: function set(value) {
            if (originalEventDescriptor)
                originalEventDescriptor.set.apply(this, arguments);
            else
                eventPropertyHolder = value;
        }
    });

    var originalDoPostBack = window.__doPostBack;

    window.__doPostBack = function hackedDoPostBack() {
        hackEventVariable = true;
        originalDoPostBack.apply(this, arguments);
        hackEventVariable = false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are using latest Firefox version. It seems a Firefox problem.
- Try with a different browser.
- Make sure your cloned button have the same JavaScript inline like original button.
- Check this [link](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2016/02/12/wtf-microsoftajax-js-vs-use-strict-vs-firefox-vs-ie/)

Comment: I tried every mentioned options but nothing work for me. I am facing this issue in FF and IE. It is working fine in Chrome.

Comment: @DivyaSharma Have you even tried modifying the script mentioned in the link in fourth option and refreshing cache’s browser?

Comment: Yeah, I have placed the above mentioned function in my script but again I am getting the same error.

Comment: I have commented on [Dave](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/48328/dave)'s question, because he did the same [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207183/send-form-via-jquery-access-to-strict-mode-caller-function-is-censored).